# Did AlphaVantage drop the swedish stock exchange?

Tags: data, market-data, historical-data, tick-data

I have used AlphaVantage in the past to get data for the Stockholm Stock Exchange: I don't remember exactly the symbol I used, but it was something along the line of OMX:ABB or STO:ABB (for, say, ABB).

I am now trying to once again using AlphaVantage to pull Swedish stock data, but I cannot find any swedish ticker anymore.

Using the symbol search (with the Excel plugin) and looking for (as example) "swedbank", I am able to find OTC product quoted in USD and EUR, but not the official ticker on the Stockholm exchange.

Am I doing something wrong, or AlphaVantage has simply dropped OMX?
I tried to mail AlphaVantage and ask, but got no answer..

Comment: Where you able to solve this? I think the correct format would be [Code].ST But it just leaves an empty output. Please let me know if you solved it.

Comment: Unfortunately no. As far as I can tell, swedish stocks are still missing from AV.

Comment: seems they were not licensed providers and had to drop markets https://github.com/prediqtiv/alpha-vantage-cookbook/issues/1